# Why do I get a userId duplicate key error even though my model does not have user as the primary key?

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, djongo

I have an Interactions model which inherits from the predefine django user model, but I have the messageId to be the primary key.

models.py:

```
class Interaction(models.Model):
messageId = models.TextField(max_length=5000,primary_key=True, unique = True)
user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key = False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
reciever = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True,default='')
sender = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True,default='')
date = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True,default='')
subject = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True,default='')
label = models.TextField(max_length=5000,blank=True,default='')
```

I have a dictionary called data which stores the information required. In views.py

```
entry, created = Interaction.objects.get_or_create(messageId=data['id'])
entry.user = request.user
entry.sender = data['from']
entry.reciever = data['to']
entry.date = data['date']
entry.subject = data['subject']
entry.label = data['label']
entry.save()
```

So while running the code there are messages with the same user but obviously different message ids

user is not my primary key yet I keep getting the error
`djongo.sql2mongo.SQLDecodeError: FAILED SQL: UPDATE "mainapp_interaction" SET "user_id" = %(0)s, "reciever" = %(1)s, "sender" = %(2)s, "date" = %(3)s, "subject" = %(4)s, "label" = %(5)s WHERE "mainapp_interaction"."messageId" = %(6)s
Pymongo error: {'index': 0, 'code': 11000, 'errmsg': 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: 5d02255b9ccf640b8c608ee1_mysitev6.mainapp_interaction index: user_id_1 dup key: { : 16 }'}`

Comment: It's a `OneToOne` field so I think a user can only belong to one interaction. You can fix it by changing it to `ForeignKey` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter that it's not the primary key. It's a `OneToOneField`, so there can be at most one entry per user in the database. Logically, I believe it should be a `ForeignKey`, and you don't need the `primary_key=False` flag.

Also, I recommend using `models.DateTimeField()` for storing dates (I don't know the exact use of your model, but if the fields are what they say they are, you should consider this).

Good luck!

Comment: oh yes, I should have had it as a foreign key instead. Thanks!